# Hammer.js with .toggleClass function

Tags: jquery, toggleclass, hammer.js

I'm trying to use hammer.js to toggle a class on *tap* event. It's essentially a card that will flip from front to back when tapped.

My original code before implementing hammer.js was:

```
$('#audioPanelContainer').click(function({
  $(this).find('#audioCard').toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

This worked just fine with both click and touch events until I started using hammer.js for other things. Now it works only on click. My question is, how can I edit this to make it hammer.js friendly?

edit: I have tried this script and it does not work at all.

```
$('#audioPanelContainer').hammer().on("tap", function(event) { 
    $(this).find('#audioCard').toggleClass("flipped"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should attach a `hammer`'s `tap` event handler on your container. Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TadeasPetak/jqakz5s9/) for an example.